# Error pulling companies user is admin of in LinkedIn

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I'm currently trying to pull the list of company pages a user is the admin of with the LinkedIn API and am getting the following response:

```
Array
(
    [response] => {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Member does not have permission to get companies as admin.",
  "requestId": "R1LHP32UKD",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1482357250945
}
    [http_code] => 403
)
```

The call works perfectly when authenticated as the same user in the [LinkedIn API Console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin).

Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

Even though I had made sure the app had the *rw_company_admin* permission checked off, I wasn't passing that in the scope when requesting oath2 authorization.

My fixed code below:

**The call:**

```
return $linkedin->getAuthorizationUrl("r_basicprofile w_share rw_company_admin", $thisurl);
```

**The function:**

```
public function getAuthorizationUrl($scope, $callback)
{
   $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
      'client_id' => $this->api_key,
      'scope' => $scope,
      'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
      'redirect_uri' => $callback,
    );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['Linkedin_state'] = $params['state'];
    $_SESSION['Linkedin_callback'] = $callback;

    // this is where to send the user
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get user token of `linkedin` user 
Use `Socialite` or REST API package for `oauth`.

Once you having user token it is pretty simple to fetch Company list under admin user

```
$token = 'uflefjefheilhfbwrfliehbwfeklfw';    // user token
$api_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?oauth2_access_token=".$token."&format=json&is-company-admin=true";
$pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));
```

You have get `$pages` json array of list of company profile.